# How do you say things like "The ________ Principle" in Japanese?

Tags: nuances, phrases

What are Japanese equivalents to saying that something is a principle, doctrine, or philosophy? You know, things that would be phrased as something like "The ________ Principle/Doctrine", or "The Philosophy of ________" in English?

I've found a couple of ways, using words like 法、理、原理、原則、義、etc. but I'm not sure which to use or how to use it as to form normal-sounding phrases with the proper nuance.

Comment: Not sure whether this is right, but maybe try 「論・理論」.

Comment: Well for something like the Archimedes Principle, that's アルキメデスの原理{げんり}.  I think 論 is more like "theory".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on where you use it, but if you look at famous usages they are translated into as:

- [Archimedes' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle)　 [アルキメデスの**原理**](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A1%E3%83%87%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE%E5%8E%9F%E7%90%86)
- [The uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle)　 [不確定性**原理**](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8D%E7%A2%BA%E5%AE%9A%E6%80%A7%E5%8E%9F%E7%90%86)
- [The Monroe Doctorine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monroe_Doctrine) 　[モンロー**主義**](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E4%B8%BB%E7%BE%A9)
- [Philosophy of science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_science)　 [科学**哲学**](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%A7%91%E5%AD%A6%E5%93%B2%E5%AD%A6)
- [the Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)　 [ピタゴラスの**定理**](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%94%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B4%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE%E5%AE%9A%E7%90%86) or 三平方{さんへいほう}の定理
- [Theory_of_relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_relativity) 　[相対性**理論**](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%9B%B8%E5%AF%BE%E6%80%A7%E7%90%86%E8%AB%96)